# google recaptcha image selector styling in lightning communities

Tags: recaptcha, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have implemented Google reCaptcha V2 in the salesforce lightning community. Everything works fine except the styling of the image selector. I am not able to position the image selector and also the images load on top of the submit button, Tried various css alterations, but was unable to fix it. Has anyone faced similar issue with captcha in lightning communities, please do let me know if there is a fix. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these;

```css
.cUBC_CommunityCreateAccount html body > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 400px !important;
}

.ui-widget html body > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 400px !important;
}

.cUBC_CommunityCreateAccount html body div:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 400px !important;
}

.ui-widget html body div:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 400px !important;
}

.cUBC_CommunityCreateAccount html body > div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 400px !important;
}

.ui-widget html body > div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 400px !important;
}

.cUBC_CommunityCreateAccount html body div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 400px !important;
}

.ui-widget html body div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 400px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ci Boz. the iframe is wrapped within a div now, so what do you mean by the wrapping html element id? I wanted to attach the html which i see in the console , but dont know how to attach a screenshot for the comment.

Comment: Hi @Ci Boz, yes i am wrapping the iframe within a div, you can see it here https://vivin-ubccrm.cs142.force.com/urcrmprosp/s/create-account

Comment: @vivinmathew I actually went to version 2 Google Recaptcha and inpected it, https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo  there is no  class or id on the elements. So i found this css solution. I edited the answer. Please check it. It does work it tested it. But you must wrap the repactca code with a new div or find out about the parent div and use it.

Comment: @vivinmathew I changed my answer please try these css styles.

Comment: Lol, i pasted few more, just to make sure one of them fits

Comment: No change @Ci Boz, remains the same. Anyway thanks a lot for  your help .

Comment: Ashame. very annoying.